# Equivalence of two definitions of the Legendre transform

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $I$ be an open interval and let $f:I\to\mathbb R\:$ be a convex function with an invertible derivative $(f')^{-1}:=\phi$. Then
$$f^*(y):=\text{sup}\ \{xy-f(x):x\in I\}=\phi(y)y-f(\phi(y))$$
for all $y\in f'(\mathbb R)$.

How do you prove this or where can I find a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the $x$-derivative of $g:=xy-f$ is $y-f^\prime$, a stationary point occurs at $x=\phi(y)$. Since $g$ is concave, [it follows](https://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/gop/t) that we have found its global maximum.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I make use of the convexity to prove that $\phi(y)$ is the maximum of $g$? $g$ should be concave, but so is the logarithm, which does not have a maximum.

Comment: @Filippo But a stationary point of a concave function is a maximum thereof.

Comment: Thank you for improving my edit :)